# wborder issues(error,problem) in ncursesw

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, ncurses

hi during my assignment with ncurses i changed header file ncurses.h to ncursesw/curses.h to use korean_utf-8.

The problem is that after I changed header, the border of window which i made by wborder() crashed(=misalignment, not proper order) like below:

[image]

and after I make new window and wrefresh it gets worse like image below

[image]

Hope somebody can help me please. I spent quite long time to find about this problem but I didn't find proper one. I guess something happened cause of chaing header ncurses to ncursesw.

```
//header before I include : #include <ncurses.h>
//header i changed: 
#include <ncursesw/curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
//I also add setlocale(LC_TYPE,ko_KR.utf-8");


void insert_page() {
    vector<WINDOW *> contents;
    contents.push_back(newwin(30, 75, 0, 0));
    wbkgd(contents[0], COLOR_PAIR(1));
    contents.push_back(subwin(contents[0], 25, 35, 3, 3));
    wborder(contents[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    contents.push_back(subwin(contents[0], 25, 35, 3, 39));
    wborder(contents[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(contents[0]);
    wgetch(contents[0]);
}
void test_page() {
    vector<WINDOW *> contents;
    contents.push_back(newwin(30, 75, 0, 0));
    wbkgd(contents[0], COLOR_PAIR(1));
    contents.push_back(subwin(contents[0], 20, 35, 3, 3));
    wborder(contents[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    contents.push_back(subwin(contents[0], 20, 35, 3, 38));
    wborder(contents[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    contents.push_back(subwin(contents[0], 3, 25, 24, 26));
    wborder(contents[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(contents[0]);
}
```

Comment: This is not C but C++ (vector is used), so please remove the C tag.

Comment: You should share the original header and a diff, so we can be specific on what changed. Also do not tag C in a C++ question.

Comment: sry, i changed thanks

Comment: The code-fragment is too incomplete to even guess.  See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  That comment about changing the header hints that you didn't change the library used in the example.

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks for comment. SinceI'm short of english, could you explain the meaning that i didn't change the library used in example?  I changed header ncurses.h to ncursesw/curses.h thank you

Comment: something like `gcc -o foo foo.cpp -lncurses` versus `gcc -o foo foo.cpp -lncursesw` (the "w" is a different memory-layout).

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem! Shared my experience hope that someone get help.

i already checked all the proposed comment(like check lncursesw when compiling or setlocale etc,,) written at my question before I wrote my question, and my problem happened just changing ncurses.h to ncursesw/ncurses.h header file.

My answer was this. If you want to draw new windows clearly, erased and refreshed
already drawn window before draw new window. thanks for all comments :)

Comment: Please edit your answer for better readability (e.g split in paragraph).